# Web WhatsApp Web Socket Post Message

Tags: javascript, websocket, whatsapp, wss, whatsapi

I am trying to code an application that can send instant messages on web whatsapp. However, I could not connect to the web socket of whatsapp.

[image]

How can I connect to this socket with Javascript? Also, I couldn't parse the messages because they are in hex. I couldn't understand what kind of data I should send.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

[image]

This is how I get a socket closed error when I try to connect. I could not understand what kind of data I should send and how I should connect to the socket. I have never worked with socket before. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure the WebSocket connection code work, you need to connect to the WebSocket and handle the message,error,open and close events in the same code like this.

```
var exampleSocket=new WebSocket("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws/chat?ED=[your chat id]");
exampleSocket.onopen=function(){
    console.log("Socket opened !");
}
exampleSocket.onclose=function(){
    console.log("Socket closed !");
}
exampleSocket.onerror=function(error){
    console.error(error);
}
exampleSocket.onmessage=async function(message){
    var datas=await message.data.text();
    console.log("you received the message:",datas)
}
```

Never forget that you receive the data from the server in a Blob(my code get the Blob datas for you when you receive a message) and to send a message to the you have to send them in a blob object like this.

```
exampleSocket.send(new Blob(["your message datas"]));
```